# Object in Object Array doesn't want to store my data

Tags: java, arrays, object

fairly new to this language. Long time lurker, first time question asker.

In my program, I load a bunch of strings from a text file and then pass all of that information inside of a String array to a program that takes the data point by point (it comes in a reliable pattern) and assigns it to variables inside a class.

I use this loop to create the objects.

```
Gladiator[] gladiator = new Gladiator[(match.contestants)];
for ( int a = 0; a < match.contestants; a++) {
    gladiator[a] = new Gladiator();
    gladiator[a].populategladiators(parsedInfo,a);
}
```

Gladiator class full of public final variables which are defined in the method populategladiators. The syntax is as follows:

```
this.name = parsedInfo[0+mod][0];
this.culture = parsedInfo[1+mod][0];
this.background = parsedInfo[2+mod][0];
```

etc.

At the moment, I only load two gladiators and it seems like maybe both are being set at once with both pass throughs? Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Also, in another method in class Gladiator, should I be able to call this.name and be okay to get data about the object I specified when calling the method?

Edit: Trying to make the code look right. Giving up since there isn't much.

2nd Edit: Example of variable declaration in gladiator class:

```
public static String name;
public static String culture;
public static String background;
```

Comment: If they're `final`, then attempting to modify them in a method would result in a compilation error...

Comment: No compilation error... also, I initialize the variables as such:
public static String culture;

in the main class, not the method.

Comment: Ah, misspoke before. They are static, not final.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes a big difference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html.

Comment: Okay. That makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed your code.  I can't grok what you  mean by "both are being set at once with both pass throughs".  If you step through it in the debugger you'll certainly be able to see the error.

Comment: Okay I changed just one of the variables by removing "static" leaving just public String name; and now it gives a nullpointer exception...

Comment: Gene, when you say you fixed my code... I don't see it. Do you mean you changed it in my initial message?

Comment: A static field in Gladiator will have only one value for all Gladiator instances, so maybe that's whet you mean by 'both set at once' ?

Comment: I just formatted it to look better.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that is what was going on. It seemed like the first object's properties were that of the second object. And thank you. But how would I avoid declaring it as static without this nullpointer? Edit: Got it working. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my variables set as static, thus it wasn't allowing me to set individual variables for the objects. I just didn't understand what the static keyword meant.